# Intellij maven war project with module dependencies, how to deploy only what is needed?

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

My current project consist of:

- parent maven pom declaring each module of the project and the common dependencies
- one sub module per feature (e.g. entity auditing, export...) one of which is a war module that depend on several other modules. Note: dependencies may contain assets used by the war (e.g. html template, config files...), thus refreshing the war context might be needed on redeploy as well.

I can build the project and use tomcat to deploy an exploded version of the war. This war contains every dependency in its `WEB-INF/lib`folder correctly. Now if I'm modifying one of these dependency in IntelliJ I would like to be able to deploy only this module into the exploded war, how could I do that? At the moment I'm `maven package` the dependency and do a redeploy on the tomcat instance...

Comment: You can try to create a new exploded artifact in IDEA that will package everything you need into a single application and will use module compiler output so that you can [hotswap the changes without redeployment](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html).

Comment: Actually at the moment I have an exploded artifact which contains my war. But how could I explode the dependencies (at the moment JARs in WEB-INF/lib) as well and make IntelliJ able to deploy any of those whenever I change one?

Comment: If these jars are built from your modules you can configure module dependencies and include module compiler output, this way `.class` files will be used instead of `.jar`. I don't think that you can hotswap jars.

Comment: How can I actually do that?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are trying to do is some kind of hot deployment. You have several solutions, which are not directly related to IntelliJ but to Java applications in general:

- in debug mode, the JVM allows you to [hotswap classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping) only if you changed method bodies
- if you want to support class/methods/fields addition/removal etc, you should take a look at [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/), which also supports reloading lots of framework configurations

Out-of-the-box hotswapping is quite limited, so I'm affraid there's no satisfying solution for your problem if you do not intend to buy/use a dedicated tool for hot deployment.

Comment: IntelliJ does hotswaping successfully. It's only when I'd like to update one of the dependencies (packaged in a JAR) that it's not anymore able to.

Comment: I also have multi-modules maven projects, and when I make modifications in a Java class located in a dependency, hotswapping works as expected when I `make` my project in IntelliJ (not using maven). But if you want to reload let's say static content located in a dependency (xml files, images, JS etc.) then it's not possible by default. JRebel allows this, though. I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.